# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException with Multiple JdbcTemplate and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am using spring-boot-starter-jdbc and trying to use multiple Jdbc DataSources, everything worked when I used named Beans for my JdbcTemplate and then used @Qualifier to inject the right JdbcTemplate into my repository.

Application:

```java
package my.app;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Autowired
  private MyRepository repository;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    List<Stuff> stuff = repository.getStuff();
  }
}
```

Configuration:

```java
package my.app;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean(name = "datasource1")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db1.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource1() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "db1")
  public DataSource db1(@Qualifier("datasource1" DataSource ds) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
  }

  @Bean(name = "datasource2")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db2.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource2() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "db2")
  public DataSource db1(@Qualifier("datasource1" DataSource ds) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
  }

}
```

Repository:

```java
package my.app;

@Repository
public class MyRepository {
  private JdbcTemplate db1;
  private JdbcTemplate db2;

  @Autowired
  public class MyRepository(@Qualifier("db1") JdbcTemplate db1, @Qualifier("db2") JdbcTemplate db2) {
    this.db1 = db1;
    this.db2 = db2;
  }
}
```

When I instantiate MyRepository everything is fine.

I did a little refactoring to try to make new classes for Db1JdbcTemplate and Db2JdbcTemplate so I could inject them without qualifiers. Unfortunately when I do this I get the following exception:

Here's what I attempted to do:

Removed named JdbcTemplate Beans from AppConfig:

```java
package my.app;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean(name = "datasource1")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db1.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource1() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "datasource2")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db2.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource2() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
}
```

Created 2 new classes for named JdbcTemplates:

```java
package my.app;

@Component
public class Db1JdbcTemplate extends JdbcTemplate {
  @Autowired
  public Db1JdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("datasource1") DataSource ds1) {
    super(ds1);
  }
}
```

```java
package my.app;

@Component
public class Db2JdbcTemplate extends JdbcTemplate {
  @Autowired
  public Db2JdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("datasource2") DataSource ds2) {
    super(ds2);
  }
}
```

Modified MyRepository to use those:

```
package my.app;

@Repository
public class MyRepository {
  private Db1JdbcTemplate db1;
  private Db2JdbcTemplate db2;

  @Autowired
  public class MyRepository(Db1JdbcTemplate db1, Db2JdbcTemplate db2) {
    this.db1 = db1;
    this.db2 = db2;
  }
}
```

So I have @Component annotations on both of those so I expected to be able to be registered and be able to be Autowired. However when I run things I get the following exception:

> Error creating bean with name 'repository' defined in file
>   [/Users/me/spring/target/classes/my/app/MyRepository.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'my.app.Db1JdbcTemplate' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {}

Any ideas what I need to change or how I can debug further? I can always go back to the working version but I'd prefer to be more explicit when possible so the compiler can help me out instead of runtime errors caused by a typo'd Qualifier name.

Answer (score 2):

A more standard way of doing this and avoid typos in qualifier names is to avoid using qualifier names, and instead use Qualifier annotations:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Qualifier
public @interface DB1 {
}

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Qualifier
public @interface DB2 {
}
```

and then, when defining your beans:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db1.datasource")
  @DB1
  public DataSource dataSource1() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean
  @DB1
  public JdbcTemplate db1(@DB1 DataSource ds) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db2.datasource")
  @DB2
  public DataSource dataSource2() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean
  @DB2
  public JdbcTemplate db1(@DB2 DataSource ds) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
  }
}
```

And finally when injecting your beans:

```
public class MyRepository(@DB1 JdbcTemplate db1, @DB2 JdbcTemplate db2) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the main concern is typos, just define your names as constants (something like `public static final String DATASOURCE1 = "datasource1";`) and consistently use those in your qualifier annotations instead of string literals. No need to add new classes or interfaces.

Comment: First of all I'd like to figure out why this doesn't work like I expected it to. Then I can determine if a different refactoring is appropriate.

Comment: There's no obvious problem with your configuration as presented. If you want ideas on how to further investigate, here are 3:
1. Revert to the working solution and change one piece at a time until something breaks to find the problem.
2. Use breakpoints to debug which beans are being found and initialized.
3. Update your logging for spring to return information on bean creation.